# ActiveX Collision

Tags: javascript, activex

I know this question is hard to answer without seeing the full actual code but I'll try anyway.

I have a single ActiveX project which I use for two different ActiveXs.
Each "ActiveX" is compiled and wrapped in a CAB with different ID (GUID) and name.

When I have only one of the ActiveXs installed, everything works fine.
Once I install the second ActiveX I start to face weird problems, for example.

One of the methods is:

```
STDMETHOD(SetOrientation)(/*[in]*/ BSTR configuration);
```

which is called from javascript in a HTML page.

When I put a breakpoint on both the javascript and in the C++ (ActiveX) code I see that the javascript passes the right configuration string but once it gets to the ActiveX c++ code I get a "bad pointer".
Again, when only one of the ActiveXs is installed, everything works fine.

Any idea?
Thanks.